Do guest users count against the free quota in Firebase Authentication?
I'm new(ish) to Firebase, and I'm building an application that uses Realtime Database and I'm working on some rules for it. I'm planning on requiring authentication but signing in with guest so that only my apps can use it. Do guest/anonymous users count against the Firebase monthly limit of 50k users and 50 monthly active users (or more on the Blaze plan)?

According to the pricing documentation, the limit you're referring to is only relevant when you've enabled Identity Platform.  You haven't said if that's what you've done, so we don't know for sure what your limit is.
If you haven't enabled Identity Platform, there is no monthly user limit.
If you have enabled Identity Platform, your project has limits according to the linked documentation I provided above.  It clearly breaks down usage between the free tier (Spark) and Blaze.

For Spark, it says: "Email, Social, Anonymous, Custom: 3,000 DAUs"
For Blaze, it says: "Email, Social, Anonymous, Custom: 0-49,999 MAUs (No cost for the first 50K), then above that: 0.0025 to 0.0055 per MAU"

Note that in both cases, you can see that anonymous accounts are included in the limits.

Thank you so much! I probably should've looked further into this . None-the-less, thanks for the help!

However under this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth it says "When you enable this feature you allow Firebase to automatically delete anonymous accounts older than 30 days. In projects with automatic clean-up enabled, anonymous authentication will not count toward usage limits or billing quotas." So that contradicts the pricing table correct?

@Dan If you believe the documentation to be in conflict with itself, you should use the "send feedback" button at the top of the page of docs, and also consider contacting Firebase support directly.
